# Alfresco model tracking error

Tags: xml, maven, tomcat, solr, alfresco

I am trying create content models for alfresco using the sts bundle.  At first, I was successfully able to login to alfresco share and see all the changes that I made.  Suddenly out of no where, I started getting this "solr model tracking" error that is preventing me from logging in.  I have been stuck trying to fix this bug for days and I also can't seem to find a clear solution to this problem.  I tried everything myself from reinstalling alfresco to updating different configuration files and yet nothing seems to work.  Here is the error:

```
2018-08-13 10:37:45,207  ERROR [solr.tracker.AbstractTracker] [SolrTrackerScheduler_Worker-37] Tracking failed
 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 07130256 GetModelsDiff return status is 404
    at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getModelsDiff(SOLRAPIClient.java:1157)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModelsImpl(ModelTracker.java:249)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModels(ModelTracker.java:207)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.doTrack(ModelTracker.java:167)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AbstractTracker.track(AbstractTracker.java:185)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.TrackerJob.execute(TrackerJob.java:47)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
```

Comment: have you added any model?

Comment: I have added a new xml file called "scModels.xml".  This is to be able to add new document types.  I didn't make any changes to the already existing skeleton code.

Comment: ok please share your scModels.xml file.
this may happen if some misconfiguration is added then we can solve

Comment: Okay, I will post it down below in the comments sections so you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

You probable made an un-incremental change like changing the data type of a property, removing or renaming a property.
You will need a full solr re-index to fix your index.

---

**Update :**
FYI, even if you put solr down you should still be able to login, your problem is probably coming from the model change you made which is preventing your repo from starting up. Not being able to login, and the 404 solr is getting when trying to track repo models are both signs of repo crash during startup

Comment: FYI, even if you put solr down you should still be able to login, your problem is probably coming from the model change you made which is preventing your repo from starting up. Not being able to login, and the 404 solr is getting when trying to track repo models are both signs of repo crash during startup

Comment: Are you running an SDK all-in-one project within STS? I find that solr behaves fairly poorly when running in the SDK, especially if I leave it running. Why not just clear out your alf_data_dev directory and re-start the process?